# Need a tool to set multiple image backgrounds to transparent

Tags: image, background, png, transparent

I'm searching for a software/tool to set the image background (black) to transparent.

I want to to remove all the black and make the image transparent.

All the images are .PNG and I have around 191 hence why I need a tool to do multiple images otherwise it could take me a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `graphicsmagick` or `imagemagick` `mogrify` tool with the `-transparent black` option. When I ran it on your single sample image it looked like this:

```
gm mogrify -transparent black 'sprite sheet 4.png'
```

To do a few hundred of these, you'd use it like this:

```
for f in *.png ; do gm mogrify -transparent black "$f" ; done
```

Be sure to work on *copies* of the files -- `mogrify` modifies files "in place".

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work for some (around 30) but others it just gave me the error: Invalid background pallet index ... I know for sure there is black on every image.